# kotlin Android sortwith Array issue

Tags: android, arrays, sorting, kotlin

I use the below sortwith method to sort my ArrayList, I suppose it will sort the order number from small number to big number. Such as 10,9,8,7,6....0. But the result is not what I expected.Please kindly help to solve this issue.

```
companyList.add(companyReg)
companyList.sortedWith(compareBy { it.order })

for (obj in companyList) {
    println("order number: "+obj.order)
}
```

Println result
[image]

Comment: Can you add little more code? Also, this log is messy. Add only one occurrence of relevant part of the log

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See this example:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val xx = ArrayList<Int>()
    xx.addAll(listOf(8, 3, 1, 4))
    xx.sortedWith(compareBy { it })

    // prints 8, 3, 1, 4
    xx.forEach { println(it) }

    println()

    val sortedXx = xx.sortedWith(compareBy { it })
    // prints sorted collection
    sortedXx.forEach { println(it) }
}
```

Why this is works this way? Because in Kotlin most collections are immutable. And `collection.sortedWith(...)` is an extenstion function which returns sorted copy of your collection, but in fact you ignore this result.

Ofc you can use other methods modifying collections (like `.sort()`), or `Collections.sort(collection, comparator)`. This way of sorting doesn't required to assign new collection (because there is no new collection, only current is modified).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
companyList = companyList.sortedWith(compareBy { it.order })
```

You can check the document here https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-with.html